# Use Prolog with C# (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface, prolog, swi-prolog

I would like to know if there is an "easy" way to call Prolog (preferably SWI-Prolog) code from C# code (in a Unity context).

I have already tried to use the SWI-Prolog - [C# interface](https://www.swi-prolog.org/contrib/CSharp.html) ([source here](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/contrib-swiplcs)) however it is not well maintained and I can't make it work with the last version of SWI-Prolog 64 bits (8.2.4 as of today).

I have also seen that it is possible to send information using an [SWI-Prolog socket](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=socket) and a C# socket (or Unity Socket) but I can't make it work, and I am not sure using socket is the best idea for the performance.

The only solution working for me was using another "custom" prolog engine : [CSharpProlog](https://github.com/jsakamoto/CSharpProlog/). This allows me to integrate Prolog code in CSharp files. Yet I would like to use SWI-Prolog if possible, do anyone knows how I can do that ?

Comment: An excellent question on which I have not progressed. Until someone implements fast message-based IPC (using AMQP, hint hint) there is the HTTP-based protocol to connect to a remote Prolog engine: [Pengines](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/pengines.html%27)). I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Swi-prolog allows initiating a call from C
https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=foreign-create-query
From there, interface C and C# is possible, though require some low-level kung fu, such as machine language, byte orders, C# name scrambling, etc. I haven't tried it with SWI, though.

Comment: @peter.cyc: this sounds interesting, would love to see a real world application ... but actually, if the (good) C# interface could not be solved (see my answer, it actually works...) I would first try to peruse the C++ interface provided by SWI-Prolog, and compile it in managed C++. These are kind of things I had to do ~15 years ago...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you provided, is not apparent that the source is available [here](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/contrib-swiplcs).
Just try to compile it, to fit your target machine architecture.

I'm trying to generate the interface on Linux, with MonoDevelop, but it's not immediate, will retry later. Meanwhile, you could try on Windows. Probably will be simpler...

*edit*

Now I had the time to attempt to compile from source in Windows 10 64 bits, and so far it seems to run pretty well. I'm using VisualStudio Community 2017, and after opened the solution (contrib-swiplcs\SwiPlCs_git.sln), have defined _PL_X64 in SwiPLcs properties - compilation.

HTH

*edit*

Have uploaded [this repo](https://github.com/CapelliC/fdqueens_cs) that shows a simplified usage of SWIPlCs.
Note there is a directory (swipl_cs) where I have simply copied (unchanged) the indispensable source files from SwiPlCs.
There is a single Prolog file, that computes N-Queens problem solutions (just the first, to keep things as simple as possible) and displays the steps performed by CLP(FD) - thanks to Markus Triska for the original implementation.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have added the link accordingly.
I have already tried to compile the project on Windows and successfully obtained the DLL. However, when I try to use the DLL on another program it is not working, I have the following error: 
Unhandled exception. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: @Sis: see my edit, on Windows works as advertised

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have tried what you did in your edit (with VS 2019 but I don't think it matters). I can successfully build 64 bits DLL, but again, when I try to test it, using my own program or the tests from the sources, I got the following error: Exception thrown: 'SbsSW.SwiPlCs.Exceptions.PlTypeException' in SwiPlCs.dll
"An unhandled exception of type 'SbsSW.SwiPlCs.Exceptions.PlTypeException' occurred in SwiPlCs.dll". I think it is because my PL Engine is not well initialized even though I use "PlEngine.Initialize()"...

Comment: Well, seems better than ` System.AccessViolationException` :) If the stack trace doesn't help (do you see it in the debugger?), to simplify the problem, I suggest to start adding (part of) your sources to the C# test project you find in the distro solution. Maybe with successive approximations we can get to the point.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, I still can't find the issue, do you mind sharing your compiled DLL & XML files as well as a C# sample script you used successfully?

Comment: Sorry I have run into problems, will retry later...

Comment: Hope you are still interested in this, in case see my last edit.

Comment: Hello, sorry for my late answer. Thank you so much for your edit. I have been able to make it work. I have still to get used to the interface but I think I will be able to do what I want from that point. Again, I am very grateful.

Comment: Well, glad it helped. Maybe you could accept my answer then ? This could help others people evaluating SWI-Prolog as a viable C# 'extension'.